# gettingerror while installing the certificates

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

I was facing the issue in my application as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853446/new-certificate-issue?noredirect=1#comment24308341_16853446).. I have followed [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/) as solution ..but upon executuing the the java class installcert I got this error please advise how to proceed

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:768)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1150)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

Make sure the password that you have put in the server.xml for the configuration of ssl is correct for the .keystore mentioned.

If the password is good, then i'k afraid your keystore is corrupted and you may have to rebuild it and re-import the certs.